# C# Winform folderBrowserDialog prevent subfolder list

Tags: c#, winforms

I am using C# .Net 6.0 winform application.

I just want to hide **subfolder list** in folderBrowserDialog.
I just want to select drive (Not subfolders).

How can I do this?

[Just like this view Without subfolders while double clicking on drive](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p9J1z.jpg)

Comment: You need to effectively rewrite all the code for `FolderBrowserDialog`, and in [`FolderBrowserDialog_BrowseCallbackProc`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/system.windows.forms/R/8c7e3589101df3cc.html) you need to `SendMessage` the `BFFM_IUNKNOWN` message, giving a [`IFolderFilter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nn-shobjidl_core-ifolderfilter0 object. You can implement `ShouldShow` to tell it to hide certain items

Comment: Or simplify the UI: using a ListBox, set its `DisplayMember` to `"Name"` and its DataSource to `DriveInfo.GetDrives()`.